# Need offer letter for visa, what would be the most acceptable/usual way to approach the company?

Tags: job-offer, visa

A company gave me an email offering me an internship. It's in another country, however, so I asked for the confirmation letter (as I need to apply for visa) on Monday. It's now Thursday and I still don't have it nor a response. I already emailed them but I haven't heard back.

I don't plan to start until late Sept 2015 though and I still don't know how long the visa process will take. How can I get the company to hurry up and send me the confirmation letter? Obviously I need to chase them up in some way, but I'm unsure on the etiquette of how to go about this.

**What would be the most acceptable way for me to approach the company?**

Comment: Do you have a specific question here? Questions asking for general advice don't work well in the SE format.

Comment: Bascailly asking who should I do next?

Comment: Perhaps phone them

Comment: Visa process time depends on your nationality, residence, and the location of the internship. It is more of a travel question than a workplace question. Once you know the probable visa processing time, you can let the internship sponsor know how soon you need the paperwork.

Comment: Can you not use the email offering you the job for your visa? Or do you need a formal offer letter?

Comment: Yes, if the company is offering internships like this, they should hopefully understand the visa process and be able to help you out directly, whether with paperwork or guidance on the visa process or whatever else you need.

Comment: Yeah, I would prefer a formal letter...I "could" phone them except that would cost a lot as they are overseas...oh, I do the visa process myself thats why I need the confirmation letter

Comment: Are you sure that you have to apply for the visa and not the company? When I worked in the US under a visa, the company handled the legal paperwork for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p?s=4|1.1616

Comment: Ok, I got an email from them: "The letter is being prepared by our administrative staff. Once done, we'll sent it to you."

Answer (score 6):

> How can I get the company to hurry up and send me the confirmation
>   letter?

**You call them.**

You explain why you need the confirmation letter, and you explain the urgency. Ask if they can get it to you quickly, or perhaps fax it to you or attach it to an email so that you can print it.